# Bidirectional ManyToMany between One entity and Many entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, many-to-many

Please help me wrap my head around an issue I've been ignoring for years, and the longer I'm doing it, the more it feels like I'm doing it wrong.

In an `RDBMS`, using Doctrine ORM, I need to Task various entities. I must be able to select entities matching given Tasks. I also wish to be able to query which tasks are being used by which entities.

Imagine a classic `ManyToMany` bidirectional relationship, say `Tasks` and `Projects`, with a stub code like this:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Project
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Task", inversedBy="projects")
     */
    protected $tasks;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Task
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Project", mappedBy="tasks")
     */
    protected $projects;
}
```

All clear, but this is a simple scenario with just two entities.

**My question is:** what if I have an awful amount of entities like the Project (think: User, Company, ...) that I want to be able to relate to Task objects (direction "various entities -> Task") while maintaining the capability to see list "All Tasks" in one place, and the capability to show a link to the associated entity that the task belongs to (Project, User, Company, ...)

**My current approach in question is:** I am choosing between (a) adding a new property into my Task entity every time I want to establish a new bidirectional relationship or, (b) I'm sticking with a unidirectional relationship, which lets me assign a Task to any number of other-side entities, but does not let me easily work out which other-side entity is the task related to.

**The problem I see**: Consider 100s of other-side entities that must have a relationship with Task. Do I have to create 100s of `ManyToMany` properties linking `Task->OtherSideEntity`? When looking at the "Task Detail" screen, how would I work out which "Other Side Entity" is related to the task?

I could create a string property holding the name of the entity on the other side, and once I fetch the Task property, I could fetch the other side in a separate query, but that feels extremely clunky.

I must be inventing the wheel here, this must be a common issue. What's the best practice here? What am I missing? Is `Doctrine/RDBMS` not suitable for taking large amounts of disjunct objects in a system?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Show us concrete example e.g. for 3 entities which should have relation to tag. I can't imagine case where you need tags to different entities. It is clear, why article should have many tags. But what is the case where you need to tag something else then article with same set of tags.

Comment: I changed the problem domain in the question. Tag is now Task, and an Article is now, for example, User, Project, or a Company. I hope it makes the core issue stand out better. It's not about "Tags" as such. It's about [One common entity][ManyToMany][Multiple disjunct entities] relation and about the best way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You can split many-to-many relationship and have relation table as entity. Personally I never use many-to-many relationship, because most of the time you will need to add some metadata to relationship.

Here is an example, where `article` and `photo` entity can be tagged with same set of tags.

```
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var ArticleTag[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ArticleTag", mappedBy="article")
     */
    private $tags;
}

class ArticleTag
{
    /**
     * @var Article
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="tags")
     */
    private $article;

    
    /**
     * @var Tag
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tag")
     */
    private $tag;
}

class Photo 
{
    /**
     * @var PhotoTag[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PhotoTag", mappedBy="photo")
     */
    private $tags;
}

class PhotoTag
{
    /**
     * @var Photo
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Photo", inversedBy="tags")
     */
    private $photo;

    
    /**
     * @var Tag
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tag")
     */
    private $tag;
}

class Tag
{
    private string $title;
}
```

Relation table contains compound primary key to preserve only unique pairs. With this design you only need to make relation table for every entity that can be tagged.

You can retrieve the tags with one additional getter:

```
foreach ($photo->getTags() as $tagRelation) {
    echo $tagRelation->getTag()->getTitle();
}
```

You can retrieve all entities that contains particular tag:

```
$this->entityManger->createQuery('SELECT entity FROM \Article entity INNER JOIN entity.tags tags WHERE tags.tag = :tag');
$this->entityManger->createQuery('SELECT entity FROM \Photo entity INNER JOIN entity.tags tags WHERE tags.tag = :tag');
```

Comment: Thanks Pavol. I agree with what you wrote, and I guess it does address half of the problem (some entities not being present in all systems): A Photo would co-exist with PhotoTags etc., leaving the Tag entity out of the problem.

I still can't see an easy way to make Tag-centric stats out of this, though: without knowing which additional weak entity table are there (PhotoTags, ArticleTags, ...), how would we query the model to get information such as "Tag1 is used by 2 articles and 5 photos; Tag 2 is not in use; Tag 3 is used by 1 photo"? You'd need to know what *Tag entities are there first.

Comment: I don't see why there is problem to know which entities could be tagged before writing a query. 
SELECT COUNT(article_tag) FROM \ArticleTag article_tag WHERE article_tag.tag = :tag;
SELECT COUNT(photo_tag) FROM \PhotoTag photo_tag WHERE photo_tag.tag = :tag;
Of course you must always list every entity that is taggable. This is the drawback while using relational databases. It is best for preserving data integrity.  But if that is not your primary target, use non relational database where you can achieve what you want. In the end if it is only for statistics non-relational database is good.

Comment: The problem is that you end up having to have a piece of the code that must be aware of what's on the "other side" of the common re-usable entity (Tags, Tasks, whatever we call it). Either it is the entity (lots of collections), or it is a service class, that must be aware of all the relations. It just introduces some boilerplate code every time there is a new relation. I'm not saying it can't be done or that it is wrong. I'm asking here because it does not seem to be DRY enough and I might be missing something. It looks I'm not, though. I'm a bit happy-sad about that :-)

Comment: Maybe the problem is with framing the question. I can't quite put a finger on it, but maybe the real question goes along the line of "is it possible to query entities of a unidirectional ManyToMany relation from the side of the relation which is not aware of the other side?" and "Is it possible to **automate** discovery of all of the 'owning'(?) entities of such relation". The automation would solve the problem I have. Doctrine is aware there is a relationship from Something to Task. Is there any efficient execution-time way it can provide the information to the rest of the application?

Comment: It looks like you don't want to define **relations** between entities and want filter them by same common property. This is not how **relational** database works.